# Move from firebase to firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app that contains USERs and EVENTs.
Each event has several users and each users has several events.

In Firebase, both events and users as "details" key(see json below), and those details are duplicate so all the event users has the details of the event, so in my main activity I have a recyclerview that shows those events easly (and the same way for users list inside event activity.
To sync all those duplicates I use firebase functions.

Now I want to move ti firestore but I'm not sure how should it be.

From what I see I can have list of users IDs in event document and then do a query for all events with user.id = current_user_id.
The issue is that I have more fields per user (expenses, and I want to add more) So either I have also subcollection for each user, or have more complicate list.

Can I query the events according to their subcollection id?

I will appreciate any help with that.

The current Json:

```
    {
      "events" : {
        "-L7v0K***" : {
          "average" : 110,
          "details" : {
            "date" : {
              "date" : 1520354933426
            },
            "location" : "Tel Aviv",
            "name" : "test"
          },
          "items" : {},
          "require_transactions" : [ {}],
          "totalexpenses" : 220,
          "users" : {
            "ARKuwgrDHcNnXHoPlCgIBXOObjD3" : {
              "details" : {
                "uid" : "ARKuw***",
                "userEmail" : "r***g@walla.com",
                "username" : "R** G***"
              },
              "expenses" : 20
            },
            "pDFtk***" : {}
        },
        "-L84Gg***" : {}
        }
      },
      "users" : {
        "ARKuw***" : {
          "details" : {
            "uid" : "ARKuwg***",
            "userEmail" : "r***g@walla.com",
            "username" : "R** G***"
          },
          "events" : {
            "-L7v0Kx***" : {
              "date" : {
                "date" : 1520354933426
              },
              "location" : "Tel Aviv",
              "name" : "test"
            },
            "-L97_3***" : { }
        },
        "TAJK6***" : {}
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is pretty close to firestore, i also started everything with firebase realtime and moved to firestore, to have more complex queries.

So, as i understood, you will have two primary collections, you can create them by:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users')
firebase.firestore().collection('events')
```

inside users you will have a subcollection called events to trigger all events a specific user have, so it will be like this:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection('events')
```

To make queries, for example, to get all events that a specific user is attending you can type:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection('events').get()
```

(here you can do filters like limiting, 'where', byId... by 'field equals to'... all of this is the documentation)

this will return all eventsId that are in the collection he attended.

Remember to work thinking on scale to get lower cost.
If you can explain more the task you need i can work in a solution.
Documentation of firestore is very easy.

Comment: From what you are saying, in users/{id}/events I will hold doc of event ID only?
Or duplicate the event collection?

Is it possible to hold reference so it won't be duplicate?

What I currently done is in events/{eventId} I have subcollection of users for some details, and also a map of maps that hold just the users id. 
Then I can do the following query:
mFirestoreDatabase.collection(EVENTS).whereEqualTo(USERS + "." + mUser.getUid(), true);